# Angular 9 service variable changes to undefined after function call, within the same file

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-services

I have a interface defined as so:

```
export interface Action {
    (...args: any[]): void;
}
```

A service defined as so:

```
import { uuid } from 'uuidv4';
import { Action } from '../interfaces/action';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root',
})
export class SocketService {
    private onMessage: Action[] = [];
    private socket: WebSocket = null;

    constructor() {
        this.socket = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8080/1234');

        this.socket.onopen = this.OnOpen;
        this.socket.onmessage = this.OnMessage;
    }

    private OnMessage(message) {
        let json = JSON.parse(message.data);

        console.log(this.onMessage);
        if (this.onMessage) {
            this.onMessage.map((x) => x(json));
        }
        console.log(json);
    }

    public set OnMessageActions(action: Action) {
        console.log(this.onMessage);
        this.onMessage.push(action);
        console.log(this.onMessage);
    }

    private OnOpen() {
        console.log(this.onMessage);
        console.log('Connection opened');
        console.log(this.onMessage);
    }
}
```

then finally a component defined as such:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { SocketService } from '../../services/socket.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-chat',
    templateUrl: './chat.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./chat.component.scss'],
})
export class ChatComponent implements OnInit {
    messages: Object[] = [];

    public get ReadyState(): number {
        return this.socketService.Socket().readyState;
    }

    constructor(private socketService: SocketService) {}

    ngOnInit(): void {
        if (!this.socketService.Socket()) {
            return;
        }

        this.socketService.OnMessageActions = this.OnMessage;
    }

    OnMessage(message: any) {
        switch (message.type) {
            case 'history':
                this.messages = message.data;
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

When the setter function is called, the first console log displays an empty array, which is expected, the push happens and the second console log displays an array with 1 item. Again, expected.

The issue is, when the OnOpen and OnMessage functions are called the array is undefined.

The logic behind the Actions interface is something that I was attmepting to mirror from C#'s/Unity's actions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `this` context in your function `OnOpen` does not refer to SocketService instance

Let try rewrite your `OnOpen` function like this

```
OnOpen = () => {
     const _this = this
     console.log(_this.onMessage)
}
```

Comment: Oh! Interesting, i don’t remember having to write functions like that in angular, I found that part of react weird. But I will give this a chance when I get home. With your answer is the const for this require or convention?

Comment: It's require because of variable declaration but you can use ```let```. The idea is capture context of ```this``` SocketService

Comment: Thanks that did the trick, I was wondering if it was possible to achive this with a similar syntax to what i was using orginally? Just preference in syntax, I tried just adding static but that did work. Thanks again!

Comment: You can assign like that ```this.socket.onopen = this.onOpen.bind(this)```.